# Creating groups and members

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Is this a good idea to manage members of a group like so:

*Assuming members can belong to one group and no other

*Simplified model

```
Group:
  name
  someid

User:
  name
  ForeignKey(Group)
  state #integer 0-no group 1-waiting for approval from a group admin 2-belong to an group
```

Something like facebook groups

Answer (score 2):

Having `state` in `User` table doesn't look good to me. It introduces dependency between `User.group` and `User.state` - `group` should be null if state equals 0, and non-null if state is 1 or 2. Also, column name is very confusing (I'd expect `User.state` to reflect user status (say active/inactive), or part of address (e.g. California/New York) , not state of relationship between user and group).

I'd put value in `User.group` only when user belongs to group, and handle requests in separate table `user_group_request (user_group_request_id (PK),user_id, group_id, request_date, request_text, request_state,response_date)`. When user wants to join group, you add a new record into `user_group_request`. Setting `User.Group` should be part of approval routine. Also, depends on your model, you may want to add unique constraint on `user_group_request(user_id, group_id)`, so one user cannot send multiple requests.